# append some element after every nth element using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a ul li structure like below and need to add blank li after every second element, how its possible with ng-repeat in angular js.

```
    <ul>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
<li class="filler"></li>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
</ul>

    <ul>
<li ng-repeat="item in items">item.content</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `items.push( //push what you want...)`.

Comment: Does this `filler` element contain anything? Or it is just some kind of spacer? Maybe instead of modifying `DOM` tree, you should try using styles? I.e defining a style for `li:nth-child(2n)`

Comment: The filler using for a kind of spacer. So need to be render with class filler.

Comment: @gaurav Unfortunately I can;t push anything to the json data, because its its huge one and its reusable for another areas.

Comment: `ng-class="{filler:!$index%3}"`

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `ng-repeat-start` with `ng-repeat-end`

```
<li ng-repeat-start="item in items">{{item.content}}</li> 
<li ng-repeat-end ng-if="$index % 2 == 1">Filler</li>
<!--  OR -->
<li ng-repeat-end ng-if="$odd">Filler</li>
```

If the filler is purely a style element you can use css to manage it without using `ng-repeat-end`

```
li:nth-child(odd):after{
  display:block;
  content: ' ';
  /** other filler rules **/
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/fb9R1lydgNmNwYxgxG6t?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: What `%2` does ? in `ng-if="$index %2 == 1"`.

Comment: @YOU ohhhh, I never even knew there was a `$odd`. I knew $last and $first but not that one...perfect thnx

Comment: @gauravbhavsar it is a modulo operation. you should look that up in a javascript arithmetic operators reference

Comment: @charlietfl  ahh, got it, result should be 1 after dividing by 2. Many thanks.